# Single model update for multiple changes in NSArrayController subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller

I implemented an `NSArrayController` subclass to implement row reordering with bindings, using the code included in [this post](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/274/a-moveable-beast) as a starting point. In the `-tableView:acceptDrop:row:dropOperation:` method, I perform the following:

```
[self removeObjectAtArrangedObjectIndex:removeIndex];
[self insertObject:object atArrangedObjectIndex:insertIndex];
```

The above code updates the model twice (one for each statement). 
For my purposes, I would like to have only one update.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need the single update in the first place? That information might help us to get a better suited answer..

Comment: As I mention in my question, I am implementing row reordering. I only consider that it is semantically appropriate to have a single update if a row gets rearranged (deleted+inserted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
[_content removeObject: [objects objectAtIndex: removeIndex]]; // < Here's the hack
[self insertObject:object atArrangedObjectIndex:insertIndex];
```

Where _content is in fact the content array of the controller.
The above works fine in my case (as described in my question).

Answer (score 0):

There's always the possibility of replacing the entire array if you want to incorporate many changes to an array into a single operation.

This might have unexpected effects for e.g. objects in the UI bound to your array, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask if you could point to the relevant method?